# How can I call a derived class's method from a function expecting the a base class pointer?

Tags: c++, inheritance, overloading

It has been a very long time since I did a lot of C++ coding and I have forgotten much.  Can comeone help to point me in the correct direction?

Assume I have a the following classes:

```
class A
{
  // Normal Class Stuff
  bool doSomething( void);
}
bool A::doSomething( void)
{
  return( true);
}
```

```
class B : private A
{
  // Normal Class Stuff
  bool doSomething( void);
  void doSomethingElse( void);
}
bool B::doSomething( void)
{
  doSomethingElse();
  return( A::doSomething);
}
void B::doSomethingElse( void)
{
  // Something Else
}
```

```
class foo
{
  // Normal Class Stuff
  void foo_stuff( A * ptr);
}
void foo_stuff( A * ptr)
{
  if( ptr->doSomething())
  {
    // Some Stuff
  }
}
```

Is there a way for me to pass in a pointer to class B and have it process B::doSomething without having  to rewrite the foo class?  In essence, I don't want to have to modify class foo, but I need to be able to  perform B::doSomethingElse before I jump to A::doSomething.

Thank you.

Comment: `virtual` function to the rescue!

Comment: Please stop splitting method definitions and declarations. It typically makes really no sense. Especially for an example here it is quite hard to read. For a simple return something you always should write it inline please.

Comment: Your code has so many typos that it is a lot work to get some minimal example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dtor()` and the function of base class must be marked `virtual`.

I changed class A's access keyword to `public` so that it can be called from class foo.

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual bool doSomething(void);
  virtual ~A() noexcept;
}
```

and it is recommend that class B overriding its parent function to append `override` keyword.

```
class B : public A
{
public:
  bool doSomething(void) override;
  virtual ~B() noexcept;
}
```